# CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB to decimal string

Tags: c++, c, math

How can i convert the SerialNumber member of a [CERT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure to a string representation in base 10 preferable using C/C++

The SerialNumber is [CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with contains two members the length, and an array of bytes.

For cases where the SerialNumber has a maximum if 8 bytes is easy to copy the bytes to a `long long` and then use standard ostream operator to convert this to a string in base 10, but not sure how can i deal with case that the serial number contains more that 8 bytes, according to X509 spec CAs should handle up to 20 bytes.

Comment: Because typically certificate serial numbers are print in base 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If efficiency is not an issue you could use a biginteger implementation (such as this one: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) and build the integer up from the byte array by doing something like this:

```
void print_dec(const char *byte_array, const size_t len)
{
    BigInteger a = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        const char &byte = byte_array[i];

        for (int bit = 7; bit >= 0; bit--) {
            a = a*2 + ((byte >> bit) & 0x01);
        }
    }

    std::cout << a << '\n' << std::endl;
}
```

(This code is untested)

Answer (score 1):

[CryptBinaryToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa):

```
DWORD len = 1024;
auto sn = new wchar_t[len];
CryptBinaryToString(
    pCertContext->pCertInfo->SerialNumber.pbData,
    pCertContext->pCertInfo->SerialNumber.cbData,
    CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW,
    sn,
    &len);
```

The result can be like this `b910cfe1ba35ecd2`.